# Running multiple regressions in R for different IDs with panel data

Tags: r

I am new to R, but I would need to run several simple regressions for different IDs with panel data.
I have 4 columns 1. IDs 2. time 3. Y 4. X and i would need to regress Y~X for each ID. I have 100 IDs with 120 time period per ID, so I would need to run 100 simple regressions with 120 observations.

How can I do it?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

We can either use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, coef(lm(Y~X)), by = ID]
```

Or to get the `pvalues`

```
setDT(df1)[,  summary(lm(Y~X))$coef[,4], by = ID]
```

If we are using `broom`, then we can get more columns of output

```
library(broom)
setDT(df1)[, glance(lm(Y~X)), Species]
```

---

Or with `broom/dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   do(model = lm(Y~X, .)) %>%
   glance(model)
```

**Reproducible Example**

```
data(iris)
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>%
    do(model = lm(Sepal.Width ~Petal.Width, .)) %>%
    glance(model)
#     Species r.squared adj.r.squared     sigma statistic      p.value    df     logLik       AIC       BIC deviance df.residual
#       <fctr>     <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl> <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
#1     setosa 0.0541735    0.03446878 0.3724741  2.749265 1.038211e-01     2 -20.546993 47.093987 52.830056 6.659375          48
#2 versicolor 0.4408943    0.42924626 0.2370691 37.851387 1.466661e-07     2   2.043799  1.912403  7.648472 2.697685          48
#3  virginica 0.2891514    0.27434209 0.2747206 19.524930 5.647610e-05     2  -5.326334 16.652669 22.388738 3.622626          48
```

and with `data.table/broom`

```
as.data.table(iris)[, glance(lm(Sepal.Width~Petal.Width)), by = Species]
#     Species r.squared adj.r.squared     sigma statistic      p.value df     logLik       AIC       BIC deviance df.residual
#1:     setosa 0.0541735    0.03446878 0.3724741  2.749265 1.038211e-01  2 -20.546993 47.093987 52.830056 6.659375          48
#2: versicolor 0.4408943    0.42924626 0.2370691 37.851387 1.466661e-07  2   2.043799  1.912403  7.648472 2.697685          48
#3:  virginica 0.2891514    0.27434209 0.2747206 19.524930 5.647610e-05  2  -5.326334 16.652669 22.388738 3.622626          48
```

Comment: thank you very much! the only thing is that my R can't find the glance function. Is it in a pacage that i probably have not installed?

Comment: @Beatrice the `glance` is from `library(broom)`  If you havne't installed it, `install.packages("broom")` and then load `library(broom)`

Comment: thank you very much!! I will try it right now!

Comment: My R can't seem to load broom package. I succesfully installed it but then when i try to load it this error comes out : Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘tibble’
Inoltre: Warning message:
package ‘broom’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Errore: package or namespace load failed for ‘broom’

Comment: @Beatrice Can you update your R version to new ?

Comment: I will try! thank you I am having so many issues with my panel data!

Answer (score 1):

The nlme package has `lmList`:

```
library(nlme)
fm <- lmList(Y ~ X | ID, DF, pool = FALSE)
```

or use `pool = TRUE` (the default) if you want a common pooled variance.  Also check out these methods which operate on `"lmList"` class objects:

```
methods(class = "lmList")
```

Comment: thank you i tried like you said but, how can i pull out the pvalues associated to the coefficients? thanks!

Comment: I tried but it doesn't show the pvalues!

Comment: It certainly does show the P values.  Try `example(lmList)` and observe that the output is a two component list (one component for the intercept and one for `age`) such that each component contains 4 numeric columns and whose last column is the P values -- one for each subject.